# Recieved Action not defined in App swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I been working on my project for a while, however, suddenly this happend and all my work is failed, how to fix it? Thank you very very much

[image: This is what happened, ! is added next to each Action in the whole project]

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the actions that display the exclamation mark, by clicking the "X" at the left of them, and reconnect them from the storyboard view.

Comment: Well, I can't see your project from here. If you'd like to post it on github or similar, I'm happy to take a look at it. Otherwise, you're just not providing any info so it's impossible to help further.